# Getting this error: "new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" | opencv, python

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently developing a method for detecting and logging camera 'wobble',  this will eventually be running parallel to various object detection, and tracking models. I am very new to opencv, although I have a fair bit of general programming experience.

It is very early days, and I am currently experimenting with different technologies, however, I am having some trouble.

I keep getting the following error:"new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple" whenever I run the code below.

The issue occurs after invocation of the cv2.createHanningWindow() function. I believe it is an issue with the parameterization, I just cant figure it out.

I understand this issue is most likely trivial, however, I appreciate any, and all help.

Thanks for the help!

```py
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import math

path = "New folder\\*.jpg"

frames = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(path)]

n=0

h, w, c = frames[0].shape

x = int(w)

hann= frames[0].copy()

while n < len(frames): 

    #do if first frame
    if n == 0:
        initial = frames[n]
        prev = initial.copy()
        cv2.createHanningWindow(hann, x)

    shift = cv2.phaseCorrelate(initial, prev, hann)

    radius = math.sqrt(shift.x*shift.x + shift.y*shift.y)

    if radius > 5:
        #draw circle and line showing shift direction
        center=h, w
        cv2.circle(frames[n], center, 5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.line(frames[n], center, (center.x+shift.x, center.y+shift.y), (0,255,0), 2)


    cv2.imshow('frame', frames[n])

    key = cv2.waitKey(3000)
    if key == 27:
        break

    prev = frames[n].copy()

    n=n+1

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
<ipython-input-30-3889c798574e> in <module>
     22         initial = frames[n]
     23         prev = initial.copy()
---> 24         cv2.createHanningWindow(hann, x)
     25 
     26     shift = cv2.phaseCorrelate(initial, prev, hann)

SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Comment: See arguments at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d7/df3/group__imgproc__motion.html#ga80e5c3de52f6bab3a7c1e60e89308e1b. Your x, needs to be a two dimensional size as a tuple (w, h) and you are missing the 'type' argument.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, friend. I have consulted the doc and updated my code. I am still getting an error:

```python
        cv2.createHanningWindow(hann, (h, w), cv2.CV_32F);
```

Output:

```python
<ipython-input-5-80f53e29204a> in <module>
     22         initial = frames[n]
     23         prev = initial.copy()
---> 24         cv2.createHanningWindow(hann, (h, w), cv2.CV_32F);
     25 
     26     shift = cv2.phaseCorrelate(initial, prev, hann)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Comment: checking `help(cv2.createHanningWindow)` you can see Python uses arguments in different order: `cv2.createHanningWindow((h,w), cv2.cv2.CV_32F, hann)`

Comment: I have another problem guys, much appreciated.
```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c4453a91e5c3> in <module>
     29     prev64 = np.float32(prev)
     30 
---> 31     shift = cv2.phaseCorrelate(prev64, initial64, hann)
     32     radius = math.sqrt(shift.x*shift.x + shift.y*shift.y)
     33 

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\phasecorr.cpp:523: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src1.type() == CV_32FC1 || src1.type() == CV_64FC1 in function 'cv::phaseCorrelate'```